# Minimal cover functional dependency

Tags: database, relational-database

I am having some trouble with this textbook question.

Find the minimal cover for the relation `R(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I)`,

where the functional dependencies are:

```
E->B,I,H,D
I->F
A->C
F,C->G
B->D
```

How do I get rid of the extraneous LHS attribute? Also, how do I find the key for this relation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a transitive dependency in `E->B,I,H,D` since `B->D`, thus you can remove `D` from the RHS of `E`.  I see no other redundant dependencies.  If you follow the arrows in reverse, you'll see that `R` is determined by `E,A`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `E -> I, I -> F, F,C -> G`, can you therefore remove the `C` from `F,C -> G`  Giving you a minimal cover of:

```
E -> B
E -> I
E -> H
I -> F
A -> C
F -> G
B -> D
```